# can't dismiss IE pop-up in selenium tests running on Jenkins

Tags: internet-explorer, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I use Selenium WebDriver for UI testing. I run tests in Jenkins (use ant as build tool). I need to run tests in Internet Explorer browser. Then I first run tests from cmd using ant I get pop-up window in IE:

[image]

I clicked once and all was ok. But then Jenkins runs the tests this pop-up appears. How can I dismiss this?
I can't manually click in browser. I tried this:

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.accept();
```

But it doesn't help. How to solve this issue.

Comment: Well what user does Jenkins run as? You need to accept it manually for that user, and only once.

Comment: To understand the problem, every pop is not an alert. In your case, this is to be setup for the first usage. open browser manually and set up this. if you still facing the issue, update us.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of alert.accept();
try alert.dismiss();
Also check if Jenkins is running these tests headless or browser comes up.